# Excel/VBA - How do I use BloombergUI .Subscribe to pull BDS?

Tags: vba, excel

I am running into a problem where Bloomberg formulas do not load while the VBA is running. I would like to use the BloombergUI to resolve it.

Colin Legg's response [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/414626-bloomberg-links-macros.html) works for pulling BDP data, but I cannot get it to work for BDS formulas. Does anybody know how to modify the code?

```
Dim xlCalc As XlCalculation Sub Test1()
    'early bound - reference to Bloomberg

    'save the calculation setting and then set to automatic
    xlCalc = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    Sheet1.Range("C2:H4").Formula = "=BDP($B2,C$1)"
    BloombergUI.RefreshAllStaticData
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "HardCode" End Sub   Sub HardCode()
    Sheet1.Range("C2:H4").Value = Sheet1.Range("C2:H4").Value
    Application.Calculation = xlCalc End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like one of these:

[Excel Bloomberg API callback in macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33900687/excel-bloomberg-api-callback-in-macro/35511387#35511387)

[VBA to refresh Bloomberg data not running in proper order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33661436/vba-to-refresh-bloomberg-data-not-running-in-proper-order/35511699#35511699)

If you need to use the values returned by Bloomberg in VBA, you need to wait for all the values to return first.