# Calling Bloomberg BQL queries from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

For complex reasons, I want to automate the calling of a Bloomi BQL query in VBA.

I am changing the inputs to a BQL.Query formula in the Excel sheet from a VBA script, and calling Application.Calculate to run the query. The display changes to "N/A Requesting Data ...". In the VBA I wait a bit (using Wait()) and even throw in a DoEvents() for good measure.

```
While rngOS.Value < 0
   Application.Calculate
   Sleep 2000   'Waits 2000 ms
   DoEvents
Wend
```

Trouble is, the BQL.Query just doesnt return. Only when I end the VBA script, does the actual data come back into the worksheet.

Ideally I would have a synchronous way to just call BQL.Query from VBA and wait for the return.

All suggestions welcome!

Comment: Code should be ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a pointer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33667663/829571

In substance: schedule your function to run a bit later, check if BQL is done (for example by counting the number of "N/A Requesting Data") and if not done, schedule the function a bit later again, etc. Once the count of N/As is down to 0, you know the update is finished and you can proceed with the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks assylias! The method of scheduling the same macro to run recursively, and handing back control to Excel in between is working well ... I can kick it off and come back later when it is done.

Comment: An update. In the end, I used a VBA wrapper for the Bloomi COM API, to request the data via synchronous BDH and BDP equivalents.

Comment: @DS_London If you don't need BQL, that's more robust indeed.