# How to allow time to refresh BDH formula from Bloomberg via VBA in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook-addin, bloomberg

I'm running a macro in which it selects a ticker in a cell, pastes it in another one, which is linked to a BDH formula. Then, it copies one of the values brought by Bloomberg and then copies and pastes it in another cell.

The macro repeats for 20 tickers, so I put it inside a for statement. The macro doesn't "give time" to Bloomberg to refresh.

I tried `application.wait`, `application.run`, etc..

```vb
Sub Atualizar_Relatorio()

    Dim Cont As Integer
    'Dim Ticker As String
    Cont = 0

    For Cont = 0 To 20

        ' Copy and paste the ticker in the cell where bloomber formula is linked
        
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Cells(4 + Cont, 4).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Historical").Cells(17, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
         
        ' Copy the values from BDH and paste in the other worksheet
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Historical").Cells(19, 4).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Cells(4 + Cont, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Cells(4 + Cont, 20).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Cells(4 + Cont, 7).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Historical").Cells(16, 8).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Cells(4 + Cont, 9).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Historical").Cells(19, 8).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Cells(4 + Cont, 13).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: A similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62577490/calling-bloomberg-bql-queries-from-excel-vba

Comment: The answer @DS_London provided is the best approach: convert your code to use blpapicomlib2. It might look intimidating at first but if you're going to be doing this kind of thing it's worth investing the time. The more synchronized way would be add something like `Check_API` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35511699/4258124 and start the next section of your loop after the data returns from BB.

Answer (score 2):

This question comes up quite often (indeed I have asked it myself), so here is the solution that I have used with the code in case it is useful for anyone else. The issue is that the BDH() spreadsheet function is asynchronous ie it returns immediately, gets the data in the background and then tells Excel when it is done. Since Excel only has one execution thread, it only reacts to this callback when it has finished processing the VBA sub-routine.

An alternative to calling a VBA function recursively (see other answers to similar questions) to wait for the BDH data to return is to *write a synchronous VBA spreadsheet function*. Depending on your level of confidence with VBA you might want to try this approach. I also have the equivalent BDP/BDS function call, but have omitted that here.

This function calls directly the Bloomberg data API, and does not return until the request has been completed. *It does not offer all the options of the BDH call* (but these can be added into the code if needed) and just returns **daily data**, ending with the most recent available. One plus is that the data comes back as an array, so can be used as an array parameter to other Excel functions.

**Usage:**
=getBloomiHistory(ticker,fields,startDate,includeDates)

**Parameters:**

- ticker: any Bbg Ticker (eg 'EUSA2 Curncy')

  fields: any Bbg historical    field, or array of fields (eg 'PX_MID')

  startDate: a specific start    date as an Excel Date (eg
  '21-May-2021'), or a string (eg '20210521'    or '-1CY')

  includeDates: defaults to True. If False the return series doesnt
  have the dates, and is a single vector of values. As this is an array function, the returned data can be used directly as a parameter for other functions.

**Returns:** A variant containing the historical date from startDate to today.

Example:

[image]

**NB. In order to run the code, the reference to the Bloomberg COM API needs to be ticked in Tools / References**. I prefer early-binding using references, but you can switch to late binding using the VBA `CreateObject("blpapicom2.Session")` in place of the New() call, and defining all the objects as Object, though you then need to find out all the BlpApi constant definitions too, using the Object Browser in the VBA IDE (hit F2).

[image]

VBA code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim g_Session As blpapicomLib2.Session
Dim g_Service As blpapicomLib2.Service

'Function to set up the Bloomberg session once
Private Function CheckSession() As Boolean
    If g_Session Is Nothing Then
        Set g_Session = New blpapicomLib2.Session
        g_Session.Start
        g_Session.OpenService "//blp/refdata"
        Set g_Service = g_Session.GetService("//blp/refdata")
    End If
    CheckSession = True
End Function

Public Function getBloomiHistory(strSecurity As String, rngFields As Variant, vStart As Variant, Optional bIncludeDates As Boolean = True) As Variant
    Dim vRet As Variant
    
    CheckSession
    
    Dim req As blpapicomLib2.REQUEST
    Set req = g_Service.CreateRequest("HistoricalDataRequest")
    req.GetElement("securities").AppendValue strSecurity
    
    Dim vFields As Variant
    vFields = rngFields
    Dim strFields() As String
    Dim lFields As Long
    
    If IsArray(vFields) Then
        Dim lr, lc, lRows, lCols As Long
        lRows = UBound(vFields, 1)
        lCols = UBound(vFields, 2)
        lFields = lRows * lCols
        
        ReDim strFields(1 To lFields) As String
        Dim lstr As Long
        lstr = 1
        
        For lr = 1 To lRows
            For lc = 1 To lCols
                strFields(lstr) = vFields(lr, lc)
                req.GetElement("fields").AppendValue vFields(lr, lc)
                lstr = lstr + 1
            Next lc
        Next lr
    Else
        ReDim strFields(1) As String
        lFields = 1
        strFields(1) = vFields
        req.GetElement("fields").AppendValue vFields
    End If
    
    req.Set "nonTradingDayFillOption", "NON_TRADING_WEEKDAYS"
    req.Set "periodicityAdjustment", "ACTUAL"
    req.Set "periodicitySelection", "DAILY"
    
    Dim strStart As String
    If IsDate(vStart) Then
        strStart = Format(vStart, "yyyymmdd")
    Else
        strStart = vStart
    End If
     
    'endDate defaults to Today
    
    req.Set "startDate", strStart

    g_Session.SendRequest req
        
    Dim evt As blpapicomLib2.Event
    Dim msgIt As blpapicomLib2.MessageIterator
    Dim msg As blpapicomLib2.Message
    Dim eltRef As blpapicomLib2.Element
    Dim eltSecurities As blpapicomLib2.Element
    Dim eltSecurity As blpapicomLib2.Element
    Dim eltData As blpapicomLib2.Element
    Dim eltFieldDataArray As blpapicomLib2.Element
    Dim eltDate As blpapicomLib2.Element
    Dim eltValue As blpapicomLib2.Element
    Dim dt As Date
    Dim vt As Variant
    
    Dim bExit As Boolean
    bExit = False
    
    Do While Not bExit
        Set evt = g_Session.NextEvent
        If (evt.EventType = PARTIAL_RESPONSE Or evt.EventType = RESPONSE) Then
            Set msgIt = evt.CreateMessageIterator

            Do While (msgIt.Next)
                Set msg = msgIt.Message
                Set eltSecurities = msg.GetElement("securityData")
                Set eltFieldDataArray = eltSecurities.GetElement("fieldData")
                
                Dim nItems As Integer
                nItems = eltFieldDataArray.NumValues

                If bIncludeDates Then
                    ReDim vRet(1 To nItems, 1 To lFields + 1) As Variant
                Else
                    ReDim vRet(1 To nItems, 1 To lFields) As Variant
                End If

                Dim nItem As Integer
                Dim nValues As Integer
                Dim d As Double
                For nItem = 0 To nItems - 1
                    Set eltData = eltFieldDataArray.GetValueAsElement(nItem)
                    nValues = eltData.NumElements
                                     
                    Dim lOffset As Long
                    lOffset = 0
                    If bIncludeDates Then
                        Set eltDate = eltData.GetElement(0)
                        dt = eltDate.Value
                        vRet(nItem + 1, 1) = dt
                        lOffset = 1
                    End If
                    
                    Dim lField As Long
                    For lField = 1 To lFields
                        If eltData.HasElement(strFields(lField)) Then
                            Set eltValue = eltData.GetElement(strFields(lField))
                            vt = eltValue.Value
                            vRet(nItem + 1, lField + lOffset) = vt
                        Else
                            vRet(nItem + 1, lField + lOffset) = CVErr(xlErrNA)
                        End If
                    Next lField
                Next nItem
            Loop
     
            If (evt.EventType = RESPONSE) Then bExit = True
        End If
    Loop
    
    getBloomiHistory = vRet
End Function
```

I say 'have' used, as I now use a compiled C++ Excel .xll which essentially does the same thing but is a little faster.