# excel bloomberg function @BDH not updating fully when using vba to update date range

Tags: bloomberg

my excel vba to update bloomberg formula BDH is not working.  I use a bloomberg formula to bring in a tbill historically.  It has a start date and end date and I need to update the end date daily.  If I manually type it in it refreshes all the data just fine.  If I do it in vba the historical section does not update.

here is the excel formula

```
=@BDH(B1,B6:C6,B2,B3,"Dir=V","Dts=S","Sort=D","Quote=C","QtTyp=P","Days=T",CONCATENATE("Per=c",B4),"DtFmt=D","UseDPDF=Y","cols=3;rows=262")
```

this is what I have tried

```
Range("B3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2/15/2024"
Range("B3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "3/1/2024"
Range("B4").Select


'
'
    wksheet2.Cells(3, 2).Select

    wksheet2.Cells(7, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Replace What:="=", Replacement:="=", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Cells.Find(What:="=", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate


Application.Run "RefreshData"
Application.Run "RefreshCurrentSelection"
Application.Run "RefreshEntireWorksheet"
Application.Run "RefreshEntireWorkbook"
Application.Run "RefreshAllWorkbooks"
Application.Run "RefreshAllStaticData"

    Application.Calculate
    ActiveSheet.Calculate


    Sleep 15000
```

[image: screenshot of excel]

basically, cell a7 updates just fine... but the dates in a8-a100 do not update.  but again, if I type it in manually everything updates just fine.

does anyone know what I am doing wrong

I tried putting it in a different method and it still doesn't work.

```
    Range("B3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2/15/2024"
    Range("B3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "3/1/2024"
    Range("B4").Select
    
    'Range("A7").Select
    'ActiveCell.Formula2="@BDH(B1,B6:C6,B2,B3,"Dir=V","Dts=S","Sort=D","Quote=C","QtTyp=P","Days=T",CONCATENATE("Per=c",B4),"DtFmt=D","UseDPDF=Y","cols=3;rows=262")"
        Range("A7").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
'
'
'    wksheet2.Cells(3, 2).Select
'
    wksheet2.Cells(7, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Replace What:="=", Replacement:="=", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Cells.Find(What:="=", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate


Application.Run "RefreshData"
Application.Run "RefreshCurrentSelection"
Application.Run "RefreshEntireWorksheet"
Application.Run "RefreshEntireWorkbook"
Application.Run "RefreshAllWorkbooks"
Application.Run "RefreshAllStaticData"

    Application.Calculate
    ActiveSheet.Calculate
    
    Application.OnTime (Now + TimeValue("00:00:15")), "InitiateProcess"
```

Comment: This is a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33661436/vba-to-refresh-bloomberg-data-not-running-in-proper-order/33667663#33667663, with a workaround.  In short. because the `BDH()` call is asynchronous it doesn't return a value until the VBA execution has finished.

Comment: I tried putting the refresh in a separate method and still doesn't work.  I updated my post to show how I did it

Comment: Refresh is not enough, you need to retry running your code every x seconds until the data is updated by using `Application.OnTime`.

Comment: Don't use VBA to refresh a Bloomberg formula. Use the API directly (see WAPI for details).